# Grouping Datasets and Counting them in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find a way to group a set of values say >=5, and then count how many groups there are, as there are large spots of values that are <5 in between each group in excel. The amount of data between each groups fluctuates, and there are over 7000 cells of data so counting them by hand is both time consuming and non-efficient.[Rows 13-61 are counted and starts counting again at row 249](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9WmK.png)[Rows 62-248 are not counted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mkTI.png).

Comment: Helper columns will likely help solve this problem. I'll try to add an answer relatively soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add two helper columns to achieve a solution.

**Column D**: Input a header of 0 (zero) and then use this formula, which looks at the value in column C and flags as 1 if that value is greater than or equal to 5. Input the following formula into cell D2 and drag it down.

```
=IF(C2>=5,1,0)
```

**Column E**: This is an IF/AND formula, where it's going to populate a 1 if the column D value is 1 and the row above it is 0. Else, populate as 0. Input this formula into cell D2 and drag it down. You'll see a pattern emerge, where it's inputting a 1 every time a new "group" starts.

```
=IF(AND(D2=1,D1=0),1,0)
```

**Lastly**, input a SUM formula wherever you like, such as cell H2. This formula is simply summing the amounts from column E.

```
=SUM(E:E)
```

That's it, done.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The classic way of doing these is to use Frequency to group row numbers where values >=5 are present into bins separated by row numbers where values <5 are present then count the number of non-empty bins:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(C2:C22>=5,ROW(C2:C22)),IF(C2:C22<5,ROW(C2:C22)))>0))
```

[image]